# Как избавиться от ошибки связанной с MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0?

Tags: android, xamarin, sdk, mono, nuget

Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — "MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0"
Возникает при попытке установить некоторые nuGet пакеты в проект xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сменить версию текущей платформы у устанавливаемых пакетов NuGet, и у самой платформы в Properties.
Смотрите, чтобы версия устанавливаемого NuGet не превышала версии имеющегося эмулятора (устройства).